# What is a good practice when setting up a users table? Looking at some newbie tutorials, but not sure how to "really" do it right

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm tinkering around with building a rest API that connects to a database.  I'm following tutorials, but the table set ups are all really basic and one of my issues has been that in the "real world" the way its done is a lot more complex and different :(

However, I'm wondering for my actual application (really small) how can I properly set up the `User` table?

For example, I have set the primary key to `userid` because that should never be changing.  Is it fine to use `long` for the userid?

Also, is it fine to lump a bunch of things together that are related to the user.. in the User table?  I know its a stupid question.. For example, I want to know if the user has signed up for the service, so `isMember`.  Or, is the user signed up for fast service, so `hasFastService`.  Or, should these things be put into a UserAttributes table by the userid?

Finally, I looked up UUIDs and I'm wondering where those fit in, in which scenarios, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question please add sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer this based on my own experience of creating users table in a project recently. The things you have to take care are basically these:

1. *Authentication:* Determine your login process and things like credential fields, user types (admin/guest/normal), whether OAuth is required or not, etc. before creating the users table. For example, whether you need a username/password to authenticate or email/password or either "username or email" with a password. The modern practice is to do away with a "username" since its redundant - an email is unique and acts as a username for all intents.
2. *OAuth:* If you are giving facebook/google/twitter logins, make provisions for that in your users table. How will you determine whether the user was a normal signup or a social login signup? A field such as "login_method" or something is useful in this regard. A second field called "user_type" maybe created for identifying the type of user account: admin/guest/employee/etc.
3. *Profile fields:* Its upto you to determine profile variables. In my last project, I used a few fields like FirstName, LastName, Theme, Timezone, etc. for the profile, but your mileage may vary.

For user-ids, it is usually best to have an auto generated *integer primary key* which is available in all modern databases.

Needless to say, never store the actual password in the password field. Just has your password and store the has instead. When the user logs in, you can hash the user-input and compare with the user table value.

Finally, DON'T confuse the user table by including related data like clients, employees, etc. All clients are users, but all users are not clients! Keep your design flexible, so as to include all kinds of users like admins, employees, etc.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks a lot.  May I ask some follow up?  1.  What about case when user wants a username to display on the site like a nickname?  2.  For the things like `isMember` or `hasFastService`, is it better to create a second table and join on the `userid`?   3.  How do you determine which data to split into another table?  I read that when there is a one-to-many relationship, split into another table.  Is that true?  THANKS PRAHLAD!

Comment: Yes, you can allow the user to set a nickname by adding that field, but ensure to validate that no other user is using that nickname upon saving - lest it creates confusion whenever its used.

Comment: Yes, for all related tables, you can link it by referring to the userid of the users table. For example, you may have a clients.userid, employees.userid, etc. as foreign keys referring to users.userid. Though personally, I simply used the email field for linking instead of userid as it serves the purpose and saves creating another field in the clients and employees table.

Comment: is there a performance benefit to using auto incrementing int userid vs email?  just curious sorry if that is stupid question.  and comparing int to int vs string to string?

Comment: I generally keep both userid and email fields in the users table. Email is a unique thing that identifies a user, but its still better to have your own primary key identifier in your system. Also, in my previous examples, its not necessary to link using an actual foreign key constraint on the table. Its fine if you have email fields in both users and clients table and refer to the users.email in your SQL joins.

Comment: In other words, use your own judgement to decide whether a separate userid field is required or not, apart from the email field. If you are running an organization where it may be useful to assign IDs to your employees  (such as 11001), its better to keep a userid field as its cubersome to use email for this purpose.

Comment: thanks!  makes sense.  finally one more question.  Is it fine to add a `createdOn` and `becameMemberOn` fields?  and if so, do I use the date data type?

Comment: These fields can be useful if you are using them in your business logic (such as taking any action based on aging) or displaying stats on them. The usage of a date/time field and what datatype to choose can vary based on your choice of database software.